# ошибка 404 в express при запросе

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

запрос выдает ошибку 404 с комментарием "Not found". В качестве бд использую Mongoose.

```
app.post('/api/auth/', function (req, res){
return  UsersModel.find({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, users) {
    if(!users) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return res.send({ status: 'false', error: 'User not found' });
    }

    if (users.pass === req.body.pass) {
        log.info("pass normal");
        return res.send({ status: 'true', error: 'User verified' });
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        log.error('Password is wrong');
        return res.send({ status: 'false', error: 'Password is wrong' });
    }
});
});
```

словно и нет такого адреса. Вот ошибка из debug: `Not found URL: /api/auth/`
Вот обработчик ошибок:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    log.debug('Not found URL: %s',req.url);
    res.send({ status: 'false', error: 'Not found' });
    return;
});
```

Comment: Так вы же явно указываете, что если нет такого толькователя, то вернуть 404 ошибку: 
if(!users) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return res.send({ status: 'false', error: 'User not found' });
    }

Comment: @AlexandrKiseloy так "User not found" и "Not found" это разные предложения.

Comment: @AlexandrKiseloyпользователь точно существует и ошибку выдает, что адреса, по которому я обращаюсь, не существует

Comment: Используйте ошибку 400 для таких ексепшенов. 404 - ресурс не найден, а не данные не найдены или неверны.

Comment: если на фронте вы парсите json, то используйте res.json({ status: 'false', error: 'Not found' });

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в чем проблема.
Адрес необходимо писать без слеша в конце, т.е. не `/api/auth/`, а `/api/auth`